# Grass Particle System How do I do this without a base?

Tags: mesh, objects, particles

I have learnt how to create random particles using objects (like grass), however these extrude from a base mesh/platform, How can I create random multiple objects (like grass) without extruding them from a particular base?

When I import this into UE4 it has a base and sits awkwardly on the landscape.

[image]

Comment: Separate the grass from the ground and don't export the ground

Comment: I believe this is related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/convert-large-particle-systems-to-one-object-efficiently. Also related, possibly duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/how-to-convert-particles-to-mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the base mesh and go to the object modifiers tab, the particle system is there. If you then hit convert then it should duplicate the grass into a separate model, where then you could delete the base.

Comment: Will UE4 generate each individual object offset and extrude them out accordingly since the mesh has bee removed?

Comment: The converted grass is just basic mesh data, no particle system if that's what you're asking