# is there a way to make hair particles an object?

Tags: particles, hair

i need to export my human 3d model to another 3d program, and that program isn't compatible with blender's hair particles, is there a way to make these hair particles an actual like object? so i could make it into an object and join it to the human mesh so i can export it properly ? if there is a way please enlighten me

Comment: Modifier panel > Particle modifier > Convert?

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/convert-large-particle-systems-to-one-object-efficiently and here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/how-to-convert-particles-to-mesh : )