# how to delete an object without deleting its particles in Blender 2.83.0

Tags: modeling, particles

OK so i made an object. And i put particles In that object OK. Now I want to delete and when i mean delete the object.. And NO i dont mean hiding the object I mean deleting it. Deleting the Object Without removing the particles on it i just want the object gone without getting rid of the particles  Is there any way to do that

I'm on Blender 2.83.0 just in case that was important

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/how-to-convert-particles-to-mesh you probably need to convert your particles into objects and then delete the mesh

Answer (score 0):

You could name the particle system and instead of the object, put that particle system on an empty. This would mean the particles would appear but the empty would be invisible.